# Factory argument in sqlite statement

Tags: android, sqlite

what is the meaning of the `factory` argument is this statement

```
public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, CursorFactory factory)
```

and when is this argument used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, CursorFactory factory)

SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory
```

Used to allow returning sub-classes of Cursor when calling query.

[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory.html)

Comment: can you explain more with simple example please